# How to test timeout() in a rxjs pipe with jasmine-marbles

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, timeout, jasmine-marbles

I have written a pipe that filters an input observable. In the pipe I specify a timeout with the timeout() operator to abort waiting if the expected value is not emitted by the source in time.
I want to test the timeout case with jasmine-marbles, but I can't get it to work.
I *believe* that `expect(source).toBeObservable()` evaluates before the source emits.

see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-marbles-testing-udfzgj?file=src%2Ftime.spec.ts)

The pipe to be tested:

```js
source = cold('a', { a: { id: 'a' } }).pipe(
  timeout(500),
  filter((a) => false),
  catchError((err) => {
    return of({ timeout: true })
  }),
  take(1)
);
```

Testing with toPromise() works as expected:

```js
expect(await source.toPromise()).toEqual({ timeout: true });
```

Testing with jasmine-marbles

```js
const expected = cold('500ms (a|)', { a: { timeout: true } });
expect(source).toBeObservable(expected);
```

fails with the error

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 2.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 500, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: Object({ timeout: true }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 500, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Support for time progression was recently added ([see jasmine-marbles PR #38](https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles/pull/38)) to jasmine-marbles 0.5.0. Additional test specs were added to the package that demonstrate one of a couple of possible ways to accomplish what you want. Here are some options I was able to throw together using your Stackblitz sample.

### Option 1

When you initialize the source observable outside the test method (e.g. in `beforeEach`), you must explicitly initialize and pass the test scheduler to `timeout` to get `expect().toBeObservable()` working. However, take note that this change will break the "should work with toPromise" test. (I don't know why, but `toPromise()` doesn't appear to work with this approach.)

```js
describe('Marble testing with timeout', () => {

  let source;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // You must explicitly init the test scheduler in `beforeEach`.
    initTestScheduler()
    source = cold('a', { a: { id: 'a' } }).pipe(
      // You must explicitly pass the test scheduler.
      timeout(500, getTestScheduler()),
      filter((a) => false),
      catchError(err => {
        return of({ timeout: true })
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  });

  it('should work with toBeObservable', () => {
    const expected = cold('500ms (a|)', { a: { timeout: true } });
    expect(source).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

### Option 2

You can refactor things slightly and initialize the source observable inside the test method (*not* in `beforeEach`). You don't need to explicitly initializes the test scheduler (jasmine-marbles will do it for you before the test method runs), but you still have to pass it to `timeout`. Note how the `createSource` function can be used with the test scheduler or the default scheduler (if the `scheduler` argument is left `undefined`). This options works with both the "should work with toPromise" test and the "should work with toBeObservable" test.

```js
describe('Marble testing with timeout', () => {

  const createSource = (scheduler = undefined) => {
    return cold('a', { a: { id: 'a' } }).pipe(
      // You must explicitly pass the test scheduler (or undefined to use the default scheduler).
      timeout(500, scheduler),
      filter((a) => false),
      catchError(err => {
        return of({ timeout: true })
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  };

  it('should work with toPromise', async () => {
    const source = createSource();
    expect(await source.toPromise()).toEqual({ timeout: true });
  });

  it('should work with toBeObservable', () => {
    const source = createSource(getTestScheduler());
    const expected = cold('500ms (a|)', { a: { timeout: true } });
    expect(source).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

### Option 3

Finally, you can skip passing the test scheduler to `timeout` if you explicitly use the test scheduler's `run` method, but you must use `expectObservable` (as opposed to `expect().toBeObservable()`. It works just fine, but Jasmine will report the warning "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS".

```js
describe('Marble testing with timeout', () => {

  let source;

  beforeEach(() => {
    source = cold('a', { a: { id: 'a' } }).pipe(
      timeout(500),
      filter((a) => false),
      catchError(err => {
        return of({ timeout: true })
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  });

  it('should work with scheduler and expectObservable', () => {
    const scheduler = getTestScheduler();
    scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
      expectObservable(source).toBe('500ms (0|)', [{ timeout: true }]);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like time progression is still getting baked into `jasmine-marbles`. I thought I'd plug `rxjs-marbles`. Good experiences using it. It supports Jasmine (among others), and they have a great collection of examples for various use cases. https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thank you @seniorquico, great response! Opposed to the Stackblitz example, I could not get Option 1 to work in my production code, I have no clue why. But I like Option 3 better anyway, because it does not involve handling a scheduler in the production code. Side note: I avoided the Jasmine warning with expect().nothing()